# Filter a list<object> by another list<object2> C# LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

Consider following lists:

```
class user {
   public int id {get; set;}
   public string name {get; set;}
   public bool selected {get; set;} 
}

class coupon {
   public string username {get; set;}
   public string coupontype {get; set;}
   public string code {get; set;}
}

List<user> lUser = new List<user>();
List<coupon> lCoupon = new List<coupon>();
```

How is it possible (with `LINQ`) to filter `lCoupon` with `lUser` so that the only values that remain are those with `lCoupon.username` field present in `lUser.name` , with `lUser.selected` being `true`?

Pseudo code:

```
lCoupon = lCoupon.Where (w => lUser.name == w.name AND lUser.selected == true).ToList();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use the LINQ `Any` method on the `lUser` list, as in:

```
var coupons = lCoupon
    .Where(c => lUser.Any(u => u.selected && u.name == c.username))
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Keep in mind that *where(any)* will traverse users list for each coupon, i.e. you will have complexity O(N*M). *Join* operation uses lookup for inner collection. That gives you O(N+M) complexity

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy: To bad I can't +1 that comment. I do wonder how the lookup is created though, after all, it's just a list without hashing as far as I am aware of.

Comment: @Stefan You can take a look at [source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,577032c8811e20d3). On first run `Lookup<TKey, TElement>` for inner collection is created. Then it is used during outer collection iteration to get 'joined' items by key

Answer (score 4):

You can also do this with a join:

```
var coupons = from coupon in lCoupons
          join user in lUser on coupon.username equals user.name
          where user.selected
          select coupon;
```

This way you can easely select values from both object types, e.g.:

```
var selectedObjects = from coupon in lCoupons
          join user in lUser on coupon.username equals user.name
          where user.selected
          select new { CouponCode = coupon.code, UserId = user.Id} ;
```

You can `ToList()` this if you prefer.

Comment: You can use `where user.selected` without comparing boolean with `true`